# How to read data from Json in Python

Tags: python, json, api

I have been playing around with the League of Legends API, but got stranded. By using this code I can read the recent matches.

```
import json

Json_games = urllib2.urlopen(url)
Games = json.load(Json_games)
```

I use this to loop through diffrent items and print specific ones.

```
for item in Games['games']:
     Gamemode = item['gameMode']
```

But the more usefull statistics such as kills are in some sort of a list. By using:

```
item['stats']
```

It outputs:

> {u'timePlayed': 2511, u'win': True, u'wardPlaced': 8, u'totalDamageDealt': 161102, u'magicDamageDealtToChampions': 33934, u'largestMultiKill': 1, u'largestKillingSpree': 6, u'magicDamageTaken': 5153, u'totalTimeCrowdControlDealt': 452, u'trueDamageDealtPlayer': 4791, u'neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle': 2, u'item2': 3089, u'item3': 1001, u'item0': 3301, u'item1': 3151, u'item6': 3340, u'item4': 3001, u'minionsKilled': 140, u'neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle': 4, **u'championsKilled': 9,** u'assists': 12, u'neutralMinionsKilled': 6, u'physicalDamageDealtToChampions': 2451, u'goldSpent': 9520, u'trueDamageDealtToChampions': 3507, u'level': 18, u'physicalDamageDealtPlayer': 30830, u'totalHeal': 1720, u'goldEarned': 14642, u'turretsKilled': 2, u'totalDamageDealtToChampions': 39894, u'totalUnitsHealed': 1, u'team': 100, u'numDeaths': 5, u'totalDamageTaken': 13629, u'killingSprees': 1, u'magicDamageDealtPlayer': 125480, u'physicalDamageTaken': 8475}

Due to lack in experience I have no idea how to be able to read them invidually, I tried opening it again in Json but that didn't work. My real question would be how to get a variable called "championsKilled" with 9 as content. I really don't need what to do and would appriciate any help and constructive critism.

[This is the whole Json file](http://pastebin.com/C4nmRw9x)

Comment: It returns a dict so you just do `item['stats']['championsKilled']`

Comment: If you want some explanations on why the Answer below works, check out my **[Beginners introduction to Riot API and JSON, using Javascript and Ajax](https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/riot-games-api/show/kvll5V8r)**. While you are not working with Javascript/Ajax, the concepts are quite similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON is loaded into a nested dictionary. The item is a dictionary, and the value for its `'stats'` key is also a dictionary. Thus you can do:

```
item['stats']['championsKilled']
```

or

```
stats = item['stats']
print(stats['championsKilled'])
```

Comment: If the answer works, then accept it by ticking the the answer ;)